# Need to place an image in the middle of content - laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a basic CMS laravel based app. I store article content using `WYSIWYG HTML Editor`. What I am trying to do is to place an image in the middle of this content. And then continue showing the rest of the article content.

Article content dd in the blade.

```
<div class="content">
<h1>Some text</h1>
<p>Some p text</p>
<p>Some p text</p>
<p>Some p text</p>
</div>
```

Can I make something like that?

```
<div class="content">
<h1>Some text</h1>
<p>Some p text</p>
<img src="URL">
<p>Some p text</p>
<p>Some p text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can look for first `</p>` and add an image after it

Comment: why you`re not using CSS? for styling?